# why does my C++ morse code translator crash if numbers are entered?

Tags: c++, string, morse-code

Hello I am programming a C++ mores code translator that allows me to translate english text to morse code i have nearly accomplished this the problem I am having is that when a number or special character is entered the program chrashes if anyone can help with this and show me how do it thank you i looked online but many poeple have this problem with no concrete awnser.

The second problom i am having is that  my teacher doesn't want me to use string toMorse (string, string[]); but instead wants me to use string toMorse(char); for the function which doesn't really make sense to me as char would only allow for a single character wouldn't it so the final question is how would i use char instead of string string and still keep it to where i can enter a line of text and it would still out put a line of mores code and if a full line isn't possible how would i do it even with only the single character sorry this is an online class and as you can see im still very new to coding (sorry i am very new and all the help is will be appreciated also i tried using map but as i never used them before i didn't know what i was doing)

also sorry but the enter codeisnt really working from the phone im using
 but this is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;
string toMorse (string, string[]);

int main ()
{
string morse[39] = {"--..--", ".-.-.-", "..--..","-----", ".----",  "..---", "...--", "....-", ". ...", "-....", "--...", "---..", "----.", ".-", "-...", "-.-.", "-..", ".", "..-.", "--.", "....", "..", ".---", "-.-", ".-..", "--", "-.", "---", ".--.", "--.-", ".-.", "...", "-", "..-", "...-", ".--", "-..-", "-.--", "--.."};
string text;

    cout << "Please enter a character, word or phrase to translate from english to morse code \n";
    getline(cin,text);
    cout << "Your text \n" << text << endl;
    cout << "Here it is in morse code \n " << toMorse(text, morse) << endl;
return 0;
}    



string toMorse (string text, string morse[])
{
int textlength = text.length();
string morseCodeValue;
string sL= " ";
string sW = "  ";
for (int index = 0; index < textlength; index++)
{
    if (text[index]!= ' ')
    {   text[index]=toupper(text[index]);
        morseCodeValue=sL+=morse[text[index]-'A']+" ";
    }
    if (text[index]==' ')
    {
        sL+=sW;
    }
} 
return morseCodeValue; 
}
```

Here is the edited version

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

const int morse_size = 39;
const string morse[morse_size] =
{
".-","-...","-.-.","-..",".","..-.","--.","....","..",".---",
"-.-",".-..","--","-.","---",".--.","--.-",".-.","...","-",
"..-","...-",".--","-..-","-.--","--..","-----",".----",
"..---","...--","....-",".....","-....","--...","---..","----."
};
string toMorse (char);

int main ()
{

string text, coded_text;

cout << "Please enter a character, word or phrase to translate from english to morse code \n";

getline(cin,text);
cout << "Your text \n" << text << endl;

for(int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++ )
{
    coded_text += toMorse(text[i]) + ' ';
}

cout << "Here it is in morse code \n " << coded_text << endl;

return 0;
}


string toMorse (char aCharacter)
{
return  morse[ tolower(aCharacter) - 'a'];;
}
```

Comment: Free clue #1: when `text[index]` is the character ';', for example: what value of the array ends up being accessed by `morse[text[index]-'A']`? Free clue #2: what values do you find in a string? If you answered 'chars' you would be correct. And now you know the answer to your second question. HTH. HAND.

Comment: ok so somthing like this should work then???

Comment: #include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

const int morse_size = 39;
const string morse[morse_size] =
{
    ".-","-...","-.-.","-..",".","..-.","--.","....","..",".---",
    "-.-",".-..","--","-.","---",".--.","--.-",".-.","...","-",
    "..-","...-",".--","-..-","-.--","--..","-----",".----",
    "..---","...--","....-",".....","-....","--...","---..","----."
};
string toMorse (char);

int main ()
{
    
    string text, coded_text;
    
    cout << "Please enter a character, word or phrase to translate from english to morse code \n";

Comment: getline(cin,text);
    cout << "Your text \n" << text << endl;
    
    for(int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++ )
    {
        coded_text += toMorse(text[i]) + ' ';
    }
    
    cout << "Here it is in morse code \n " << coded_text << endl;
    
    return 0;
}


string toMorse (char aCharacter)
{
    return  morse[ tolower(aCharacter) - 'a'];;
}

Comment: sorry edited the original question

Comment: Take a look at an ascii chart and you'll see it.  What's '0' - 'a'?

Comment: what inputs crash you program? Can you give samples? What's the error message. I can see anything outside of  letters may cause trouble.